# installation of a github module

Tags: github, pip, ubuntu-16.04, python-3.6, setup.py

this one really puzzles me.
I have 2 repos - A and B. A's requirements consist of just 2 modules (requests and pytest). In order to use A in B, I've created the setup.py file in A, included A github address in B's requirements.txt and ran pip install -r requirements.txt. Pip install has got executed without any errors. I also tried getting into virtualenv src of B and running python setup.py install. The installation of A hasn't succeeded though as I still can see pip-delete-this-directory.txt file. 
On running B I get the ImportError - one of A's files is failing. The thing is that the import error concerns pathlib - both projects are written in Python3.6 so pathlib does not need to be installed. 
The stacktrace is:

> ConftestImportFailure:
>   (local('/home/axolotl/B/venv/src/A/tests/mymodule.py'), (, ImportError('No module named pathlib',),
>   ))

What am I missing here?

Comment: Sounds like you're using python2.x py.test (perhaps system-installed?)

Comment: @AnthonySottile, yes, I must be blind! the stacktrace says 2.7 although both the repos are 3.6! I've added pytest 3.2.3 to B's requirements file, installed them and it's ok! THANK YOU :)